# Why does CPN TOOLS keep reverting my edits?

Tags: ml, petri-net

When editing a declaration I type in my changes and click on the background and it immediately reverts my text.

I have no syntactic issues, I can delete the declaration and write a new one and it accepts it just hunky dory, any ideas what's causing this frustrating behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best (unsatisfactory) answer I have come up with is that the java host running CPN TOOLS has had an error and shut down and CPN Tools is now acting erratically.

When you restart the system the editing capability is restored.